# What is the value of AX register after instruction MOV AX, [1D4B] executed?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to understand what will be the value of AX register in the following question:

Part of computer memory is shown in figure

```
Address | 1D48 | 1D49 | 1D4A | 1D4B | 1D4C | 1D4D | 1D4E | 1D4F |
Value   |  03  |  7F  |  F5  |  2D  |  5A  |  12  |  7B  |  C0  |
```

What is the value of AX register after instruction MOV AX, [1D4B] executed?

It is Little Endian and AX register is 16-bit, so is AX value 5A2D?

Comment: Yes, assuming that DS base is 0.

Comment: @prl: Or assuming that the 16-bit "addresses" are offsets in the DS segment, wherever that is in linear address-space, e.g. in a DOS .com program.

Comment: @PeterCordes And assuming that the used assembler is in `radix 16` mode and doesn't interpret the number notation `1D4B` as an error.

Comment: @vitsoft: Good point: this is actually tagged [nasm].  For this to even assemble, it would have to be written as `mov ax, [0x1D4B]` or `mov ax, [1D4Bh]`.  NASM doesn't have a `radix 16` or equivalent directive (not that I've ever noticed).  Wthout a prefix or suffix, numeric literals are base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Since AX is 16-bit, AX = data in [1D4C] [1D4B], which is AX = 5A2D;
if it were AL or AH, only the data in address[1D4B] will be copied.